# Are brain augmentations capable of interfering with orgasm?

Tags: science-based, biology, brain, sex, trans-humanism

Implants and/or augmentations in human brain are widely shown in fiction: improving and/or enhancing certain functions of the brain by artificial means can have nearly endless possibilities.

All of these, of course, and I assume, are related to certain regions of the brain - and their working mechanism, almost surely would be based on: 
* providing additional computational potential through an implanted microcomputer or 
* extending the brain's natural neural signal processing by providing more connections between neurons and/or adding neural cells into the system of the human brain.

For this question, assume that the latter is much closer to reality, because at least my personal knowledge implies it.

I've also heard (specifically [in this ASAP Science video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ioQ8a7o3Mo)) that the way orgasm happens in the brain is identical in both genders, meaning that whoever we are talking about, there is a possibility that in a given world, a given person's brain have augmentations in regions where orgasm happens.

Is it possible that the presence of an artificial neural network attached to one's brain modify the effect of orgasm - even if it's not specifically created for this purpose (="by accident")?

If yes, what kind of outputs are expectable? Hallucinations, extended length, complete loss of one or more senses for the time, seizures, maybe neither?

I assume this is highly dependent so can't be answered so easily - in this case, it is enough to explain, what are those dependencies.

Comment: Unless someone can provide some hard facts for "No it cannot", then the answer automatically becomes "Yes, it can". How? No-one knows I dare say, because our understanding of the brain is far too lacking to give an answer to that.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors in fact, I was having some issues choosing the right tag. I may change from [hard-science] to [science-based] if that helps giving place for more speculations.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely recommend that change.

Comment: @TimB done! I noticed that [hard-science] is recommended only in very specific cases anyway.

Comment: @Katamori Well the question here is what you — as the author — are looking for. What is the need that you expect to be fulfilled? Are you looking for scientific rigor? For credibility? For mere suspension of disbelief? Are you looking for exposition... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposition_(narrative) ...or for some actual narration that provides meat to the text and the story?

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors  I'm not sure if this fact would be depicted in my story at all, so currently, this is just mere curiosity, with a slight purpose on scientific accuracy. Whatever answer I get to this question can help me going on with detailing the way brain augs work in my world - or in any world with less soft sci-fi.

Comment: @Katamori Well in that case you have a wealth of other fiction to look at for inspiration. Ghost In The Shell and The Matrix are the obvious ones that spring come to mind. In GITS you have artificial materials that are growing into and over the natural brain tissue and augmenting the senses that way, whereas in The Matrix the interface is instead on the nerves going to and from the brain. Curiously, in GITS the effect is **augmentation** of reality while in The Matrix a simulation entirely **replaces** reality, despite the fact that in GITS the interface is **in** the brain.

Comment: @Katamori Personally I think that Ghost In The Shell is the more credible and realistic depiction. In The Matrix the whole concept feels  obviously born as a plot device and despite pretenses of being "deep" in terms of philosophy and the concept of what is "real" I think it fails miserably. In the end it just scratches the surface. GITS does it more realistic and with much harder questions.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors thanks! I definitely wouldn't consider the Matrix approach, as I'm way not into this whole "fake reality" concept. It's just too grim and dark for what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Katamori Well you can still imagine the **technology** without the conflict and grimdark plot element of "The machines have enslaved humanity" :)

Comment: By delivering a minute current into a specific region of mature rat, scientist observed how the subject could be turned on by a mere coffee mug. Such effect only register in short term mem but prolonged sensation could have long term benefits...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An orgasm [involves most of the brain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xqj9auWq-hc), not just a small area. So inhibiting an orgasm in the brain would be an extremely complex task and probably not easily viable.

What would be (more) easily possible though, is to simply prevent the sensory input from the body to the brain. As there are people that can orgasm from stimulation of a wide variety of body parts (and not just the genitals and erogenous zones alone), the easiest and most fail-safe method would be to temporarily interrupt electric activity in all [afferent nerve fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afferent_nerve_fiber) from skin receptors, causing the whole body to go numb.

No sensations, no orgasm.

Answer (score 0):

### The artificial neural network has anxiety.

Anxiety is the mental state of being constantly on your guard. All the appetites are tuned down and the body redirects blood flow to the lungs and limbs and away from the stomach and other, less important organs so you can focus all your energy on fight or flight. In the modern age of plentiful food and shelter, it's often a disorder, but we needed it back when there was lion behind every bush - and evolution hasn't gotten the memo, so now when we get a worrying memo form our boss, our body gears up to fight a lion.

The point is, an anxious brain cannot spend any resources on the basal pleasure of sex, so orgasm fails. No need to muck around with the nerves to make the body go numb, just have the neural network be anxious, constantly on guard for any threats and draining all the joy out of its host's life.

Okay, that might be worse.